# Is it possible that $P(\lim \sup \{X_n = 0\}) = P(\lim \sup \{X_n = 1\}) = 1$?

Tags: probability, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Perhaps this is a very silly question, and I'm probably just confusing some really obvious property, but suppose that I have a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables with probability $1/n$. Now, by Borel-Cantelli, I have that $P(\lim\sup X_n =1) = 1$, since $$\sum^\infty_{i=1}P(X_i =1) = \sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac{1}{n} = \infty$$

But, by the same logic, I would have $P(\lim\sup X_n = 0) = 1$. What am I confusing here?

Comment: You are mixing up the two very different statements. One is the statement that the events $A_n=\{X_n=0\}$ satisfy that the event $\limsup A_n$ has probability $1$. (Essentially saying that except on a set of outcomes of measure $0$ we have that $(X_1,X_2,\dots)$ contains infinitely many $0$'s. The other is that statement that (the number) $\limsup X_n$ is equal to $0$. Borel-Cantelli tells you about the first statement; saying that with probability $1$ the sequence $(X_1,X_2,\dots)$ contains both infinitely many $0$s and infinitely many $1$s.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit for more information. On a separate note, the statement $P(\limsup_n X_n = 1) = 1$ is true.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe, so $P(\lim \sup \{X_n=0\}) = P(\lim \sup \{X_n = 1\})$  can both have probability 1, since they occur infinitely many times with prob 1?

Answer (score 1):

As commented, the problem is that $P(\limsup\{X_n=1\})$ and $P((\limsup X_n)=1)$ are totally different things.

For the example, choose random variables $A_n$ with $$P(\limsup\{A_n=1\})=1$$
and $B_n$ with $$P(\limsup\{B_n=0\})=1,$$and let $$X_n=\begin{cases}A_k,&(n=2k),\\ B_k,&(n=2k+1).\end{cases}$$

Note that $\limsup\{A_n=1\}\subset\limsup\{X_n=1\}$ and $\limsup\{B_n=0\}\subset\limsup\{X_n=0\}$.

Comment: So this $P(\lim \sup \{X_n = 0\}) = P(\lim \sup \{X_n = 1\}) = 1$ is indeed true?